# Modify slow query log rotation on Amazon RDS instance

Tags: mysql-5.6, amazon-rds, performance, slow-log

Our Amazon RDS instance rotates slow logs every hour, and keeps only the last 20 of them.

This is not optimal for monitoring as it prevents us from seeing any slow query that might have been running more than 24 hours ago.

Is there a way to have the slow query log rotate once a day - instead of once an hour - or any other way to keep the slow logs for a longer time?

Edit: Database is MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Which database platform are you talking about - RDS runs SQL Server, MySQL, Aurora...

Comment: MySQL. I edited the question.